# Delete all lines that don't contain a string in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

So I have around 1000 lines of a text document and was wondering if it's possible to delete all lines on Sublime Text that don't contain a certain keyword, in my case: `@`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## (Edited) Steps

To delete all of the lines **NOT** containing occurrences of the keyword, use the following:

### Mac

- Select your keyword (via double click, drag, etc, say `@` in your case)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to select all occurrences
- Hold <kbd>Command</kbd> and press <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> and press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
- Cut with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
- Select All with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete all file contents
- Paste with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

### Windows

- Select your keyword (say `@` in your case)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to select all occurrences
- Hold <kbd>Control</kbd> and press <kbd>Home</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>End</kbd>
- Cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
- Select All with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete all file contents
- Paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: No, you got it wrong, I want to delete all lines that DON'T contain that keyword :)

Comment: Just chiming in to note that this is such a clever hack/solution. :)

Comment: I've tried the windows path but seems not working :(

Answer (score 6):

Using the **Invert Selection** feature, you don't need to remove any text and then put it back. In five steps, you could do:

### Windows and Linux

- Select one instance of your keyword
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to select all occurrences
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to to select all lines which contain your keyword
- menu item **Selection** > **Invert Selection** to select all lines which do not contain your keyword
- <kbd>Del</kbd> to remove all lines which do not contain your keyword

### Macintosh

- Select one instance of your keyword
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to select all occurrences
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to to select all lines which contain your keyword
- menu item **Selection** > **Invert Selection** to select all lines which do not contain your keyword
- <kbd>Del</kbd> to remove all lines which do not contain your keyword

#### Other Advice

If you do this frequently, you may want to add a keyboard shortcut for the **Invert Selection** command. For example, open **Preferences** > **Key Bindings** and add the line:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+i"], "command": "invert_selection" },
```

If you do this even more frequently, you may want to record a macro in order to do all of the steps at once. See menu item **Tools** > **Record Macro**.

Comment: Ah thanks for the Cmd + L line selection shortcut! Also Invert Selection is a nifty feature. :)